Mounting a combi boiler in a dirt basement with fieldstone foundation
I just bought a 1790s house with an old (30+ years) furnace and water heater (20+ years) located in southwest New Hampshire. We want to convert this system to a combi boiler as I can do all the work myself. The only set back I’m having is deciding how I want to mount the boiler since we have a dirt floor and a fieldstone foundation.
My initial idea was to dig holes for two fence posts and set them into concrete, attach plywood to the fence posts, and then the boiler and its components to the plywood. After further research I’m nervous to dig into the floor at the risk of disturbing the foundation. Maybe I’m being paranoid?
I had another idea of pouring a small rat slab with anchor bolts and essentially framing a small wall with the rat slab as a “foundation” to mount the boiler to.
I don’t want to drill into the fieldstones so that is out of the question. Does anyone have any input on this? I've included a picture of the area for additional context. Thank you so much

If you dig your holes away from the walls, they won't disturb your foundation.

Thank you @Ecnerwal! Do you have any recommended distance away from the wall?

Depends how deep your post hole will be. See https://www.concretenetwork.com/concrete/footing_fundamentals/why_soils_matter.htm for a discussion and illustration of how loads transfer into soils.  If your post-hole stays out of the zone of support it should not upset the footings. In your case those are rocks, not concrete, but the support from the soil is the same.

Step away from "wall" to support the boiler for a minute and consider that you can easily build a free-standing frame with 3 or 4 legs to support the boiler, with no need to dig anything if you don't want to. Seems unlikely that the additional space will greatly impact your basement rec room dreams, as finishing that one would be a daunting task.
One easy way if you don't want to build much yourself would be a sturdy utility shelf unit, and you could (if you still want a "wall-like" part to mount to) affix a section of plywood (with a 2x3 or 2x4 stud frame if you like) between two shelves set far enough apart to allow mounting and plumbing the boiler. Use a big enough shelf unit that the boiler ends up within the footprint, so it's not trying to topple.

I think this is certainly a viable solution but I was hoping for more of a permanent solution. I worry that anything freestanding would have the potential to move/wiggle and harm/reduce the life of the plumbing joints

You can cast a slab around the feet of the shelf, and/or attach it to the framing above. There should be exactly zero frost movement inside a basement.
